# To solve given differential equation using laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am solving following diff eqn using laplace transform:
\begin{eqnarray}
y''+y= \begin{cases}
          0, & \text{if 0<t<2 $\pi$}\\
          \sin t, & \text{t>$2\pi$}
          \end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
where $y(0) =1 \space and \space y'(0) =0$.

**My attempt:** I converted above equation into

\begin{eqnarray}
y''+y= \sin t H(t-2\pi)
\end{eqnarray}

Now using the formula the laplace transform of RHS is:

$\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{s^2+1}$. This will be used in while changing the laplace transform of above diff eqn and we get

$s^2Y(s) -sy(0) -y'(0) + Y(s) =\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{s^2+1}$

where $\mathcal{L}y(t) =Y(S)$. This gives

$Y(S) = {e^{-2\pi}}[\frac {s(s^2+1) +1}{ ({s^2+1})^2 }]$.

Now I have to find inverse laplace. Is my solution till now correct? How to proceed further to find the answer. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you solve the equations independently and then stitch them together

We solve $ y'' + y = 0 $ have a unique solution $ \cos t $ that satisfy the initial conditions.

Next, we solve $ y'' + y = \sin t $ have a solution $ A \sin t + B \cos t -\frac{t \cos t}{2} $, in order for this to be continuous with the previous solution, we can solve for $ B = 1 + \pi $

In order for the first derivative to be continuous, we can solve for $ A = \frac{1}{2} $.

So we get the solution to be

$ y = \cos t $ when $ 0 < t < 2\pi $

$ y = \frac{1}{2}\sin t + (1 + \pi) \cos t - \frac{t\cos t}{2} $ when $ t \ge 2\pi $

Answer (score 0):

Notice, solve them seperatally:

- $$y''(t)+y(t)=0\Longleftrightarrow y(t)=\cos(t)$$
- $$y''(t)+y(t)=\sin(t)\Longleftrightarrow y(t)=\frac{\sin(t)-(x-2)\cos(t)}{2}$$